# How Should I Send the Magic Packet to My Drone with Scapy?

Tags: python, networking, udp, wireshark, scapy

I am trying to initiate a stream of video data from my drone to my computer. The drone runs a wifi access point for video and photo control through a mobile app (the flight controller uses a separate 2.4 GHz signal). I ran the app on an Android emulator on the computer, and I sniffed the following traffic:

[image: drone_app_handshake]
Note that after a successful connection:

- the drone sends a `PSH,ACK` packet with 20 bytes of data, which looks like this:

Drone to Client Data - Sample 1:

```
Data (20 bytes)
    Data: 637d00000180ffffd188d5ca3586d5ca00020000
    Text: c}
    [Length: 20]
```

Drone to Client Data - Sample 2:

```
Data (20 bytes)
    Data: 569500000168ffffaaac8c4c01aa8c4c00020000
    Text: V\357\277\275
    [Length: 20]
```

Drone to Client Data - Sample 3:

```
Data (20 bytes)
    Data: 1e9a00000164ffff46bdb26265bbb26200020000
    Text: \036\357\277\275
    [Length: 20]
```

- the client increments the `ACK` number by 20
- the client sends a `PSH,ACK` packet with 12 bytes of data

I scripted a TCP connection with Scapy, and I can get as far as the last PSH,ACK packet, from the client to the server (drone). Then, the drone immediately sends a `FIN` packet. I am using netcat to listen on port 6666, which is always the port to which the drone tries to send UDP packets, as fragmented IPv4 packets.

Here is the capture from the scripted connection:

[image: drone_script_handshake]

Here is my Scapy script:

```
from scapy.all import *

#SYN
ip = IP(src="172.16.10.139",dst="172.16.10.1")
SYN = TCP(sport=39921,dport=8888,flags="S",seq=2091127182,options=[('MSS', 1460), ('SAckOK', b''), ('NOP', None), ('WScale', 6)]) 
SYNACK=sr1(ip/SYN) 

#ACK
ACK=TCP(sport=39921,dport=8888,flags="A",seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq +1)
PSHACK=sr1(ip/ACK)

#ACK2
ACK2=TCP(sport=39921,dport=8888,flags="A",seq=PSHACK.ack, ack=PSHACK.seq +20)
send(ip/ACK2)

#PSHACK2
PSHACK2=TCP(sport=39921,dport=8888,flags="PA",seq=PSHACK.ack, ack=PSHACK.seq +20)
send(ip/PSHACK2/'\001\357\277\275\357\277\27')
```

Note that I originally had the value `\275` as the last four characters of the string, but then Wireshark showed the data length as 13 bytes. I omitted the last `5`, and then Wireshark reported the data length as 12 bytes. I am not sure what the significance of the digit `5` is or whether I am sending the correct 12 bytes.

These are the 12 bytes that I am sending, as observed in Wireshark:

```
Data (12 bytes)
    Data: 01c3afc2bfc2bdc3afc2bf17
    Text: \001\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\027
    [Length: 12]
```

I used the emulator to capture several successful connections, and I notice that the captured data varies in the following ways:

Client to Drone Data - Capture 1

```
Data (12 bytes)
    Data: 0174b21607b6c6fc082a7913
    Text: \001t\357\277\275\026\a\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\b*y\023
    [Length: 12]
```

Client to Drone Data - Capture 2

```
Data (12 bytes)
    Data: 01f8d7142452257d254afd91
    Text: \001\357\277\275\357\277\275\024$R%}%J\357\277\275\357\277\275
    [Length: 12]
```

Client to Drone Data - Capture 3

```
Data (12 bytes)
    Data: 0128e514ba003ceabb2821ff
    Text: \001(\357\277\275\024\357\277\275
        [Expert Info (Warning/Undecoded): Trailing stray characters]
            [Trailing stray characters]
            [Severity level: Warning]
```

Client to Drone Data - Capture 4

```
Data (12 bytes)
    Data: 01c0cf16a1c4d009a284a020
    Text: \001\357\277\275\357\277\275\026\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\t\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275 
    [Length: 12]
```

I need to understand how to send the same 12 bytes of data with Scapy. I believe that the `PSH,ACK` packet that the client sends to the drone is the magic packet and that the 12 bytes of data are the magic word.

The Android app contains a set of C++ shared objects that apparently handle the connection that I am trying to emulate.

How should I add the necessary 12 bytes of data to my Scapy script to initiate the stream of fragmented IPv4 packets to the UDP port on the client? Or, does it look like the Scapy script is correct and that the issue is with the client configuration, i.e. availability of the destination port?